# why cv2.seamlessClone throw error ' (-215:Assertion failed) '?

Tags: image-processing, opencv3.0, opencv, python

i have 3 images ( background,foreground , mask of foreground)

and all images have same size

when i run the code below it throw error :

error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1534379934306\work\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:465: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function 'cv::Mat::Mat'

code :

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

mask=cv2.imread('mask.jpg',0)
bg=cv2.imread('bg.jpg')
fg=cv2.imread('fg.jpg')


_, contours,_= cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)


center = (int(x+w*0.5),int(y+h*0.5))


output = cv2.seamlessClone(fg, bg, mask, center, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
    
    

cv2.imshow('sss',output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

bg:
[image]

fg:
[image]

mask:
[image]

can any one help me ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because some pixels of the mask going outside of `bg` and `fg`. To solve this you can add a border to all your images of value 0.

your updated code will look like this. I have not removed the border from the output image. You can remove it as your requirement.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

mask = cv2.imread('mask.png', 0)
bg = cv2.imread('bg.png')
fg = cv2.imread('fg.png')

top, bottom, left, right = 20, 20, 20, 20
border_bg = cv2.copyMakeBorder(bg, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0, 0, 0])
border_fg = cv2.copyMakeBorder(fg, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0, 0, 0])
border_mask = cv2.copyMakeBorder(mask, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(border_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

center = (int(x + w * 0.5), int(y + h * 0.5))

output = cv2.seamlessClone(border_bg, border_fg, border_mask, p=center, flags=cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)

cv2.imshow("border_mask", border_mask)
cv2.imshow("border_bg", border_bg)
cv2.imshow("border_fg", border_fg)
cv2.imshow('output', output)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

| border_bg | border_fg |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

| border_mask | output |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |